# How can I lookup CAA DNS records in Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, dns

What is the best way to look up CAA DNS records in Java 8?

Looking up CAA records using the InitialDirContext fails, since CAA records are not (yet) supported.

For example, using

```
InitialDirContext context  = new InitialDirContext();
Attributes = context.getAttributes("dns:/" + domain + ".", new String[] { "CAA" });
```

fails with

```
javax.naming.directory.InvalidAttributeIdentifierException: Unknown resource record type 'CAA'
    at com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsContext.fromAttrId(DnsContext.java:714)
    at com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsContext.attrIdsToClassesAndTypes(DnsContext.java:735)
    at com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsContext.c_getAttributes(DnsContext.java:431)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_getAttributes(ComponentDirContext.java:235)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.getAttributes(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:141)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.url.GenericURLDirContext.getAttributes(GenericURLDirContext.java:103)
    at javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.getAttributes(InitialDirContext.java:142)
```

(this works fine with other record types, like A, AAAA or CNAME)

Is there any other way to do this using vanilla Java 8? If not, which third-party libraries could be used?

Comment: Any proper DNS library should be fine doing requests for `CAA` records or any other type. But recommendations are offtopic here.

Comment: I would prefer using built-in functionality if possible, but some additional library would also be an option. I'm also happy about recommendations...

Comment: DNS libraries for android that I know of (but haven't used extensively) are dnsjava and minidns, both are on GitHub.

Comment: Does any version later than Java 8 have built-in support for CAA records?

Comment: Nope.  Not even Java 19.

Answer (score 2):

For the record, Java still does not support CAA records.  Not even in Java 19 - the latest as of 2023-01-03.

I can't find any references to this in the Java Bugs Database, so I am guessing that this won't be a priority for the Java team.

Recommendations for alternative Java DNS libraries are **off-topic**.  However, if you Google for `java caa record` and you should see some promising search hits.  For example, the "dnsjava" / "org.xbill.DNS" library.

Comment: In Google search, all results are related to create CAA record but I want to fetch list of CAA record for hostname which we can get using Linux command "dig caa geekflare.com". Is there any way I can get using JAVA InitialDirContext and fetch all CAA records.

Comment: 1) I found 3rd-party Java DNS libraries that support CAA records.  Keep looking. 2) AFAIK, no.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested above, you could use [dnsjava](https://github.com/dnsjava/dnsjava). It's stable, very easy to handle and minimal requirement is Java8.

Just a quick-and-dirty example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws TextParseException {
    Record[] records = new Lookup("google.com", Type.CAA).run();
    System.out.println(records[0]);
}
```